# Can I route using the leftmost portion of hostname with a wildcard for everything after?

Tags: domain-name-system, google-cloud-platform

I have an application where I would like it to forward traffic based on the highest-order subdomain, rather than the full domain from right to left.

So for example, I have the domains:

- `mydomainone.fake`
- `mydomaintwo.fake`
- `subdomain.mydomainthree.fake`

Is there any way that I could make the following all route to the same backend **using a single rule** like `api.*` (by way of the fact that they all start with `api`):

- `api.mydomainone.fake`
- `api.mydomaintwo.fake`
- `api.subdomain.mydomainthree.fake`

The goal here is to be able to add new tenants (`api.subsubdomain.subdomain.mydomainfour.fake`) to my application and have it respond dynamically without having to update my load balancing configuration every time a new one is configured to point to my load balancer.

The one negative implication I can think of with this is that anyone would then be able to configure a domain to point to my application. Although my application code will only recognize domains that it's set up with.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your concept correctly, then this won't work.
You can have multiple subdomains in a single rule, but you can't have something like `api.*.example.com` or `api.*.com`

Number of rules doesn't matter in this case, you will get this error:
`Asterisk may only be used as leftmost character preceding '.' or '-'`

So you'd have to add every subdomain separately.

Comment: Right, your example probably also applies to something like `api.*` as well.